# Jquery: show element by value

Tags: jquery, html, show

I'd like to show an image based on what radio button I have selected. First I hide all the images, then in the next function I'd like to show the correct one. Hiding works, I have correct value in variable value. However the line '$(value).show();' is not working for me. I've tried editing it but nothing helped. Could someone please help? How do I correctly use this code to show the img by id?
Thanks

```
/*when a radio button is clicked, hide imgs*/
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ClassRadio").click(function(){
    $(".ClassImgShape").hide();
  });
});

/*shows img based on selected radio button*/
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input:radio[name=radioshape]").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    //$("p").text(value);
    $(value).show();
});
});


<img class=ClassImgShape id=ushape src="./ushape.png" alt="u-shape" title="u-shape">
<img class=ClassImgShape id=lshape src="./lshape.png" alt="l-shape" title="l-shape">
```

Comment: What are the values ? Maybe you want `$('#"+value).show();`.

Comment: Note that you don't need two `.ready()` handlers, you can bind both `click` handlers from within the same `.ready()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$(value).show();
```

with this:

```
$('#' + value).show();
```

The value you must be getting like `ushape` or `lshape` but to show the images you need to put a `#` in front of that.

**UPDATE**

You can do this in simple way like this also:

```
$("input:radio[name=radioshape]").click(function () {
    $('#' + this.value).show();

    console.log(this.value);  
    // Check the console, if you are getting correct value
    // Above line of code needed, just for debugging purpose..
    // You can comment that out
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that I'm storing the full selector as the value of the radio input, instead of just the id, since jQuery uses that to know we are searching by id and not by another attribute. Also, you only need **one** `$(document).ready(function(){});` to call your code.

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="#image1">
<input type="radio" name="radio2" value="#image2">
<input type="radio" name="radio3" value="#image3">
<input type="radio" name="radio4" value="#image4">

<img class='hide' id='image1' src='foo'/>
<img class='hide' id='image2' src='foo'/>
<img class='hide' id='image3' src='foo'/>
<img class='hide' id='image4' src='foo'/>
```

jQuery

```
//Hide all images with class 'hide' for example
$("img.hide").hide();

//Show on click
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
   $(this.value).show(); 
});
```

Comment: Why would you use `$(this).val()` instead of the faster/cheaper/just-as-supported `this.value`?

Comment: @DavidThomas because I fail sometimes my friend, I'm human :)